# Restart function after click action with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, jquery-animate, restart

I have some function which is look like this:

```
var live_search_list = $('.live_search_list ul'),
    active_search_element = live_search_list.find('li.active'),
    search_element = live_search_list.find('li'),
    jsPane = $('.jspPane'); 

$('.bottom_search').click(function(){
    if (!search_element.last().hasClass('active')) {
        active_search_element.removeClass('active');
        active_search_element.next('li').addClass('active');
        jsPane.animate({top:"-=95px"});
    }
});
$('.top_search').click(function(){
    if (!search_element.first().hasClass('active')) {
        active_search_element.removeClass('active');
        active_search_element.prev('li').addClass('active');
        jsPane.animate({top:"+=95px"});
    }
});
```

So, problems starts after the first click, I have only one action - this with animation.   After first click function is not checking my condition again, and not changing, removing class `active`. How can I restart this function after every click on this buttons?

Comment: You want to [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) the animation?

Comment: I want to check my condition after every click, now after the first click everything is fine, but after it i have only animation action...

Comment: Are you sure that `search_element` and `active_search_element` are valid elements upon second and following clicks? +1 for what epascarello said - apart from anything - it's always good idea to stop() before starting animation again, otherwise, if user clicks several times in short intervals your animations will get queued and everything will be jumpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you make the next `li` the active class you need to recache it in `active_search_element`

```
var live_search_list = $('.live_search_list ul'),
    active_search_element = live_search_list.find('li.active'),
    search_element = live_search_list.find('li'),
    jsPane = $('.jspPane'); 

$('.bottom_search').click(function(){
    if (!search_element.last().hasClass('active')) {
        active_search_element.removeClass('active');
        active_search_element.next('li').addClass('active');
        active_search_element = live_search_list.find('li.active')
        jsPane.animate({top:"-=95px"});
    }
});
$('.top_search').click(function(){
    if (!search_element.first().hasClass('active')) {
        active_search_element.removeClass('active');
        active_search_element.prev('li').addClass('active');
        active_search_element = live_search_list.find('li.active')
        jsPane.animate({top:"+=95px"});
    }
});
```

Comment: ofcourse, now active class append to second element and stay with it forever, much thx for help, BR

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting `active_search_element` to the new active element!

The line:

```
active_search_element = live_search_list.find('li.active')
```

only selects the element at that time, it does not magically keep updating.

```
$('.bottom_search').click(function(){
    if (!search_element.last().hasClass('active')) {
        active_search_element.removeClass('active');
        active_search_element = active_search_element.next('li').addClass('active');
        jsPane.animate({top:"-=95px"});
    }
});

$('.top_search').click(function(){
    if (!search_element.first().hasClass('active')) {
        active_search_element.removeClass('active');
        active_search_element  = active_search_element.prev('li').addClass('active');
        jsPane.animate({top:"+=95px"});
    }
});
```

Comment: it works to, thx, i think also that is more flexible way for write it